# Focus on input when clicking radio button

Tags: jquery

Is there a way with jQuery that when clicking a radio button, an input gets focus?

I've tried the following but it does not work

```
<input type="radio">
<input type="text">


$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
$(this).siblings('input [type=text]').focus()
})
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove the space in `('input [type=text]')`

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LLpPb/)**

Answer (score 0):

`$(this).siblings('input [type=text]')` will select multiple input elements if they are present so you must use [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to reduce the array to the first input selected.  Also note that the space was removed from the selector.

```
$("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
    $(this).siblings("input[type='text']").eq(0).focus();
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/t75aD/

Comment: Thanks for this. I posted from my phone hence the space..!

Answer (score 0):

what you can do is place an id on your input something like: `<input type="text" id="toFocus">` and then do just:`$('input[type=radio]').click(function() {
$("toFocus").focus()
})` 
I think this could be faster.